# Is $\{a^mb^nc^{mn}\mid m>n\}$ a context-free language?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Been trying to figure it out for an hour myself and another hour looking around, I cannot find anything with the $c^{mn}$ part.

$$L=\{a^mb^nc^{mn}\mid m>n\}$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?